# Evaluating a determinant for eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

I need to evaluate

$$\left| {\matrix{
   {3 - \lambda } & 1 & 1  \cr 
   2 & {4 - \lambda } & 2  \cr 
   1 & 1 & {3 - \lambda }  \cr 
 } } \right|$$

A direct computation became relatively complicated. What direction should I take to make the solution more neat?

By the way, I was able to see that for $\lambda =2$ the determinant is $0$ so $2$ is an eigenvalue.

Comment: To me you just have to solve the polynomial. You can't apply gauss-jordan. because the pivots are not $1$.

Comment: You should practice enough so that computing this determinant isn't something you consider too troublesome, since $3\times 3$ determinants are a common source of exercises. Anyway, one can note that the columns all add up to $6$, so $6$ is an eigenvalue. The others follow easily.

Comment: @GitGud, Is the fact that all column add up to $6$ can help me with reducing the determinant?

Comment: @AlonAlon I assumed you wanted the eigenvalues of the matrix one gets eliminating $\lambda$. If you simply want the determinant of the given matrix, it still helps because the determinant will be $-(\lambda -a)(\lambda -b)(\lambda -c)$ where $a,b,c$ are the eigenvalues of the matrix without the $\lambda$'s.

Comment: If you add $(R_1+R_2)$ to $R_3$ then $R_3 = (6-\lambda, 6-\lambda, 6-\lambda)$. What would you do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying $C_1'=C_1-C_2$

$$\left| {\matrix{
   {3 - \lambda } & 1 & 1  \cr 
   2 & {4 - \lambda } & 2  \cr 
   1 & 1 & {3 - \lambda }  \cr 
 } } \right|$$

$$=\left| {\matrix{
   {3 - \lambda-1 } & 1 & 1  \cr 
   2-( 4 - \lambda)& {4 - \lambda } & 2  \cr 
   1-1 & 1 & {3 - \lambda }  \cr 
 } } \right|$$

$$=(2-\lambda)\left| {\matrix{
   1 & 1 & 1  \cr 
   -1 & {4 - \lambda } & 2  \cr 
   0 & 1 & {3 - \lambda }  \cr 
 } } \right|$$

Applying $C_3'=C_3-C_2,$

$$\left| {\matrix{
   1 & 1 & 1  \cr 
   -1 & {4 - \lambda } & 2  \cr 
   0 & 1 & {3 - \lambda }  \cr 
 } } \right|=\left| {\matrix{
   1 & 1 & 1-1  \cr 
   -1 & {4 - \lambda } & 2-(4 - \lambda)  \cr 
   0 & 1 & {3 - \lambda-1 }  \cr 
 } } \right|$$

$$=\left| {\matrix{
   1 & 1 & 0  \cr 
   -1 & {4 - \lambda } &  \lambda-2  \cr 
   0 & 1 & {-(\lambda-2) }  \cr 
 } } \right|$$

$$=(\lambda-2)\left| {\matrix{
   1 & 1 & 0  \cr 
   -1 & {4 - \lambda } &  1  \cr 
   0 & 1 & {-1 }  \cr 
 } } \right|$$

and so on

Comment: Didn't you forget to a minor in the last equality?

Comment: @AlonAlon, I left the rest for you to complete:)

Comment: I know. But I think the last equality isn't true. Didn't you forget a minor?

Comment: @AlonAlon, Sorry, let me rectify

Comment: I tried to solve it and got $2,4\pm\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: @AlonAlon, No, the third root should be $6$

Answer (score 5):

In fact, for $\lambda=2$ all three columns become equal, hence $2$ is a double eigenvalue. Then the third eigenvalue can be found from the fact thet the trace $3+4+3$ of the original matrix is the sum of eigenvalues.

Comment: Thank you, although I'm not allowed to use those theorems.

Answer (score 1):

$\lambda=2$ is a double eigenvalue, since the rank of the matrix 
$$
A-2 I = \left(\begin{array}{ccc} 1& 1 & 1\\ 2 & 2 & 2 \\ 1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right)
$$
is equal to one - it has only one linearly independent row.

Then Trace$(A)=10$. Thus the third eigenvalue is equal to $10-2-2=6$.

Therefore

$$
\det (A-\lambda I)=(2-\lambda)^2(6-\lambda).
$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I wouldn't be able to use those theorem you mentioned.

Comment: @yiorgos, another way to look at is $A - 2I$ is a rank one matrix $ab^T$ which has eigenvalues $\{0, 0, b^Tb = 6\}.$